# django delete problem - deleting more than one object with a OneToOneField relationship - got MultipleObjectsReturned error

Tags: django, django-models

I have a problem with deleting my objects. I wrote a delete method which get a list of IDs of objects to be deleted. This works fine for objects and for objects with foreign keys, but it fails if i have a OneToOneField relationship to the object which i want to delete.

This is my delete method:

```
@login_required
def delete_objects(request, model, selected_ids):
    '''
    capsulate a bulk delete method
    delete all objects found for the given model
    fails silently since model.delete() always fails silently
    '''
    object_list = model.objects.filter(pk__in=selected_ids)
    count = object_list.count()
    if count == 1:
        name = model._meta.verbose_name.title()
    else:
        name = model._meta.verbose_name_plural.title()
    object_list.delete()
    request.user.message_set.create(message='Successfully deleted %s %s' % (count,name))
    return
```

Till now I just tested it with Contact objects. Now I added a PhoneNumber model to my models. The PhoneNumber model has a OneToOneField relationship to the Contact model. If no PhoneNumber object or one PhoneNumber object is assigned to the Contact object i can delete it. But if I relate more than one PhoneNumber object to a Contact object i get an error.

This is the error message that i get:

```
MultipleObjectsReturned at /crm/contacts/
get() returned more than one PhoneNumber -- it returned 3! Lookup parameters were {'contact__pk': 4L}
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/crm/contacts/
Exception Type: MultipleObjectsReturned
Exception Value:    
get() returned more than one PhoneNumber -- it returned 3! Lookup parameters were {'contact__pk': 4L}
```

I read in the django docs

[deleting objects](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#deleting-objects)

that "any objects which had foreign keys pointing at the object to be deleted will be deleted along with it." This is the goal I want to accomplish.. but now i get an error. All I want is the objects to be deleted :D

Actually is this maybe a design problem? Is it wrong when I relate more than one PhoneNumber object to a Contact object with a OneToOneField relationship? I have chosen OneToOneField since the phone number is unique and should be related to only one contact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it wrong when I relate more than one PhoneNumber object to a Contact object with a OneToOneField relationship?

You got it. Change the relationship to a foreign key in PhoneNumber and set the `unique` option for the `PhoneNumberField`.

Should end up like this:

```
class PhoneNumber(models.Model):
    # some fields...
    number = PhoneNumberField(unique=True)
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, related_name="phone_numbers")
```

Also, just to make sure I understand how you want the constraints set up: This example assumes that a phone number will only appear once in the entire database and therefore also that only one contact can have that phone number.

In case you wanted something less restrictive, use `unique_together` in the model's Meta options like so:

```
class PhoneNumber(models.Model):
    # some fields...
    number = PhoneNumberField()
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, related_name="phone_numbers")

class Meta:
    unique_together = ("number", "contact")
```

This will allow multiple contacts to have the same phone number, but a single contact cannot have that number more than once.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together